Problem with fitting a neural network model on binary classification data
I have a dataset of 280 samples with 20 features and 0,1 results. I scaled them.
Also, having three neural network models to train data on them.
But while looping on models I receive an error with fitting.
How to resolve it?
import numpy as np
import math

import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model1 = Sequential([
    Dense(units=25, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=15, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=1, activation='linear')
])
model2 = Sequential([
    Dense(units=20, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=12, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=12, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=20, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=1, activation='linear')
])
model3 = Sequential([
    Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=8, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=4, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=12, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=1, activation='linear')
])

nn_train_error = []
nn_cv_error = []

models_bc = [model1, model2, model3]
for model in models_bc:

    # setup the loss and optimizer
    model.compile(
        loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    )

    print(f"Training {model.name}...")
    # train the model
    model.fit(x_bc_train_scaled, y_bc_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
    print("Done!\n")

    # Set the threshold for classification
    threshold = 0.5

    # Record the fraction of misclassified examples for the training set
    yhat = model.predict(x_bc_train_scaled)
    yhat = tf.math.sigmoid(yhat)
    yhat = np.where(yhat >= threshold, 1, 0)   # where in np : condition function
    train_error = np.mean(yhat != y_bc_train)  # mean in np : show the percent of misclassified

    nn_train_error.append(train_error)

    # Record the fraction of misclassified examples for the cross validation set
    yhat = model.predict(x_bc_cv_scaled)
    yhat = tf.math.sigmoid(yhat)
    yhat = np.where(yhat >= threshold, 1, 0)
    cv_error = np.mean(yhat != y_bc_cv)

    nn_cv_error.append(cv_error)

print(nn_train_error)
print(nn_cv_error)

output:
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
 last) Cell In\[109\], line 15      13 print(f"Training
 {model.name}...")      14 # train the model ---\> 15
 model.fit(x_bc_train_scaled, y_bc_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)     
 16 print("Done!\\n")

Arguments received by Sequential.call():
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 20), dtype=float32)
• training=True  
• mask=None


I have reproduced your code on a similar dataset, got an error where the
predicted values (yhat) were two-dimensional, while the ground truth labels
(y) were one-dimensional. To resolve this, I applied the ravel function to
yhat, transforming it into a one-dimensional array. This modification
successfully addressed the issue. Please refer to this gist to see the changes.Let me know if you are still facing issues
made in the code
